# Is it ok to say "eye drops are for putting into eyes"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

> ˈ[**eye drops**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/eye-drops) noun [plural]
>
> special liquid which you put into your eyes because they are sore or
>   dry, or as a medical treatment

--

[image]

My son: What is it?

Me: It is a bottle of eye drops. Eye drops are for putting into eyes.

Is it ok to say "**eye drops are for putting into eyes**"?

Comment: Yes, it's OK. A native speaker might say "... into your eyes" and add "when they're dry" or whatever.(_Your_ here means _one's eyes_, not the eyes of the person being spoken to.)

Comment: It is pretty obvious that eye drops are for 'putting in your eyes'. That's why they are called 'eye drops'.